# Process multiple XSLTs and pass the result to another XSLT for transformation in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement in my code and it is as follows:

The

- Parameters in my Java program are passed to an XSLT(X1) for processing. The X1 returns only one String value.
- Another set of Parameters are passed to another XSLT(X2) for processing.The X2 also returns only one String value.
- After Transformations the XSLT results need to be passed to another XSLT(X3) which would use the value as Variables and generate result basis the results from X1 and X2.

As far as i have been studied the XSLT variables values cannot be modified once stored. and also that these values are received as parameters when calling <xsl:apply-template name="someTemplate" > and with parameter tags.

i can implement this functionality by retrieving the result into String in Java and again Passing them as parameters to the next template. but i wanted to know if the same can be done directly via XSLT.

Please help

Edit: Xalan removed as tag

Comment: You have tagged your question as both `xalan` as well as `xslt-2.0`. That does not make sense as Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor so consider to clarify which version respectively processor you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i can implement this functionality by retrieving the result into
>   String in Java and again Passing them as parameters to the next
>   template. but i wanted to know if the same can be done directly via
>   XSLT.

**Yes, here is an XSLT 2.0 example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pP1" select="2"/>
    <xsl:param name="pP2" select="3"/>
    <xsl:param name="pP3" select="5"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vPass1">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass1">
       <xsl:with-param name="pP1" select="$pP1"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vPass2">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2">
       <xsl:with-param name="pP2" select="$pP2"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vPass3">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass3">
       <xsl:with-param name="pP3" select="$pP3"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vPass1 + $vPass2 + $vPass3"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*" mode="pass1">
  <xsl:param name="pP1" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(*[. mod $pP1 = 0])"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:param name="pP2" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(*[. mod $pP2 = 0])"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*" mode="pass3">
  <xsl:param name="pP3" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(*[. mod $pP3 = 0])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**three passes are performed, each with its own parameters. Each pass computes the sum of `num` elements, whose value is multiple of the supplied parameter. Finally, the results of the three passes are summed and returned as the final result**:

```
63
```

Exactly the same transformation can be run with an XSLT 1.0 processor, with the exception that any string `"as='xs:integer'"` must be removed from the code.

Comment: Could you please use an example where i have 3 different XSLTs and then call 2 of them in parallel and then use the result of the 2 to call the template of the 3rd XSLT and pass them as parameters..it would be very helpful..

Comment: @VineetVerma, Just remove the templates with modes and put all templates with the same mode in a different XSLT stylesheet. In the "main" stylesheet import (using `<xsl:import>`) these three stylesheets. Then execute the transformation and you get the same correct result. As for "in parallel" -- there is no such notion in XSLT -- one can never be sure whether some code paths are executed sequentially or in parallel. Not to speak that some XSLT processors perform lazy execution.So, I have answered your original question completely. If you have new questions, please ask them as ... new questions